# How to get access for user_posts in facebook graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a student doing university project in which we are developing an app that has the use case to combine social media feeds of the users. For this i need access to facebook graph api "user_post"

I have already made an app on facebook developer portal and i have written code for facebook login inside my android app but now i want to work on user feed but when i went to request permission section, they are asking for app review, business verification etc. Now problem is that how can i submit my app for review when i have not access to api in order to develop and test it.

I'm searching ways for 2-3 weeks but all solutions are not working as facebook has updated alot of things. I will be very thankful if someone will be able to help me with this facebook api access as i'm new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always test it with your account, that is admin, developer or tester in the App. `user_posts` will work with that account without review.

Comment: I have tried to get user_posts permission on facebook android sdk with the account that is admin and it throws exception "SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349013 [message]: The app requested an invalid permission."

Comment: Okay i have put my app back to development mode and now I'm able to get access the user_posts... Thanks